# Select & Drag an entire week in Full Calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

Is it possible to shift select multiple days in Full Calendar and drag them to a new date?  I have not found examples of others currently doing this in my searches.  Also, if using the "selectable" calendar where mouse click-drag is used to create an event spanning multiple days, wouldn't this interfere with a shift select to select multiple days?
Thanks,
--Rick

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is solved through the answer from this question:
[Enable Shift-Multiselect in jQuery UI Selectable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9374743/enable-shift-multiselect-in-jquery-ui-selectable)

You should be able to accomplish this through the use of a JQuery plugin in a way that won't interfere with the selectable calendar.