# Multiselect in jQuery with shift key

Tags: jquery, html

I would like to allow multiple selection of items so that the `#par` displays all 3 values selected with a shift. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9374743/enable-shift-multiselect-in-jquery-ui-selectablebelow) leads me to believe such functionality is not built in with jQuery, and needs a workaround, although it is from 3 years ago. I use jsFiddle and 1.9.1 jQuery.

```
<select id="select" multiple>
    <option value="item1">item1</option>
    <option value="item2">item2</option>
    <option value="item3">item3</option>
</select>

<br />
<p id="par"></p>
```

```js
$('#select').change(function(){
    $('#select option:selected').each(function(){
        $("#par").text($(this).text() + ", ");
    });
});
```

Comment: Where is your JSFiddle link? kindly post here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a comma separated list of the values chosen in a multiple select by using `val()` - the same as you would any other form element. Try this:

```
$('#select').change(function() {
    $("#par").text($(this).val());
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/rvnb74nb/)

Comment: thanks a lot Rory. I've been fiddling with this. How come the option:selected is skipped and it still works as expected? it looks like this code should list all the options, not only the ones selected (?)

Comment: It's simply because `val()` does all the work for you internally. It knows the type of element it's being called on, so gets the right value for the specific situation.

Comment: ok thank you, checked the docs as well and it is actually there :)

Comment: Everything is. The jQuery documentation is about the best available, for anything :)